# In Jer. 6:14 is it referring to shalom (שָׁלֹ֑ום) being used as a greeting?

Tags: hebrew, hebrew-bible, jeremiah

The Hebrew sounds like Jeremiah referred to shalom being used as a greeting.  Key to answering this question is when did the Jews start using shalom as a greeting?

וַֽיְרַפְּא֞וּ אֶת־שֶׁ֤בֶר עַמִּי֙‬ עַל־נְקַלָּ֔ה לֵאמֹ֖ר שָׁלֹ֣ום שָׁלֹ֑ום וְאֵ֖ין‬ שָׁלֹֽום׃
(Jer. 6:14, BHS2003)

```
         They have healed the wound of my people lightly, 
  saying, ‘Peace, peace,’ 
  when there is no peace. 
                 (Jer. 6:14, ESV)

   They offer healing offhand 
  For the wounds of My people, 
  Saying, “All is well, all is well,” 
  When nothing is well.
              (Jer. 6:14, JPS1985)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the prophets who are saying "Peace, peace". It is one of their faults. As a complaint against them it works best if the point is that they are falsely promising "peace" to the people.

The most immediate threat to peace is the literal warfare being predicted in the first twelve verses of the chapter. But there is also a connection between "peace" and "living in obedience to God", as we learn from Isaiah; "O that you had hearkened to my commandments! Then your peace would have been like a river and your righteousness like the waves of the sea... There is no peace, says the Lord, for the wicked" (Isaiah ch48 v18, v22 RSV).

I suggest that the false prophets are offering a double message of comfort; You are in peace with God (he is not angry with you) and therefore there will be no war.

Regarding your second sentence, the AV shows better than modern translations the early arrival of the standard greeting "Is there peace with you my brother?" or something similar. The earliest example seems to be Moses and Jethro asking each other of their peace in Exodus ch18 v7